# HUE access from LAN and internet

Tags: hadoop, web, lan, hue

I want to host Apache HUE on the local network and internet. what are the necessary configurations?
I want to access HUE from another PC in the LAN using the browser.

Comment: you are on wrong site . please use google for that

Comment: thanks, but I tried before posting here and I didn't found an answer